# Which one is key about hashMapOf in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know I can create a map object using HashMap.

The following code is from  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-map-of.html

which one is key? How can I access the map by key? `map [1]`, `map["1"]` or `map["x"]` ?

```
val map: HashMap<Int, String> = hashMapOf(1 to "x", 2 to "y", -1 to "zz")
println(map) // {-1=zz, 1=x, 2=y}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access using `map[1]`. You can refer to [this blog](https://androsketchpad.blogspot.com/2017/08/kotlin-collection.html) for more variants.

In the expression `hashMapOf(1 to "x", 2 to "y", -1 to "zz")`, `1` refers to key where as `x` is the value.

**When you print value using:**

```
println(hasmap[1])
```

**Output will be:**

```
x
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that `1` is Key and `"x"` is value when I use the structure  hashMapOf(1 to "x")

Comment: Thanks! English isn't my native language, but in my mind, maybe "value to key" is more natural English just like "assign a value to a key" , right ?

Comment: @HelloCW Iam not an expert in English either, but when you try to express "key to value" sounds more natural. e.g. "Key to success".

Comment: You can think of it like this: you're mapping _from_ the key _to_ the value. The key is what you already have, and the value is what you're looking up using that key.

Answer (score 2):

All three are possible.

In the case, you mentioned the key is

```
map[1]
```

However, if you created the map as follows:

```
hashMapOf("1" to "x", "2" to "y", "-1" to "zz")
```

the key would be

```
map["1"]
```

To add further explanation, in *HashMap* or any *Map* the Key comes before Value type. And as you notice the *HashMap<Int, String>* identifies Key(Int) type as well as the Value(String) type.